# How to make sscanf read until '\0' character

Tags: c, scanf

I want name to have all the characters remaining in the line until the `'\0'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char line[] = "1999-08-01,14.547,0.191,United Kingdom";
    unsigned int year, month, day;
    float temp, uncertainty;
    char name[100];
    sscanf(line, "%u - %u - %u, %f , %f , %s", &year, &month,
                       &day, &temp, &uncertainty, name);
    printf("%u-%u-%u,%lf,%lf,%s\n", year, month, day, temp, uncertainty, name);
}
```

I can make this work like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char line[] = "1999-08-01,14.547,0.191,United Kingdom";
    char* newline = malloc(strlen(line) + 2);
    strcpy(newline, line);
    newline[strlen(newline)] = '\n';
    newline[strlen(newline)] = '\0';
    unsigned int year, month, day;
    float temp, uncertainty;
    char name[100];
    sscanf(line, "%u - %u - %u, %f , %f , %[^\n]", &year, &month,
                       &day, &temp, &uncertainty, name);
    printf("%u-%u-%u,%lf,%lf,%s\n", year, month, day, temp, uncertainty, name);
}
```

But I find this very inelegant.

Comment: @user3121023 you are right, I had completely missed that, there is no point in this question, the answer is in the question itself.

Comment: Aside: `newline[strlen(newline)] = '\n';` overwrites the `'\0'` string terminator, so `strlen` in the the next line `newline[strlen(newline)] = '\0';` could cause havoc, but is perfectly useless, becuz you overwrite a `0` with `0`.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
char line[] = "1999-08-01,14.547,0.191,United Kingdom";
unsigned int year, month, day;
float temp, uncertainty;
char name[100];
sscanf(line, "%u - %u - %u, %f , %f , %99[^\n]", &year, &month,
                   &day, &temp, &uncertainty, name);
printf("%u-%u-%u,%lf,%lf,%s\n", year, month, day, temp, uncertainty, name);
```

`'\n'` will not be found, but since the limit of 99 wouldn't be reached, `sscanf` would continue reading until the end-of-string marker.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without putting a constant such as 99? I also find that quite ugly, because what if I had 100 characters to read into name?

Comment: @chilliefiber The limit is necessary because otherwise you would have a buffer overrun. There is a way to do it in gcc with no set limit, but it is not standard.

Comment: The extension you refer to (" An optional assignment-allocation character 'm'") is part of [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) and is more widely implemented than just glibc.

Answer (score 5):

`sscanf` is not the most elegant interface, but it has a lot of features. One of them is the ability to find out where you are in the input string, which lets you extract (or just point to) "the rest of the input".

For example, after;

```
int nchar = -1;
int nfield = sscanf(line, "%u - %u - %u, %f , %f , %n", &year, &month,
                    &day, &temp, &uncertainty, &nchar);
```

`nchar` will contain the offset in `line` of the name field (unless it is still -1, indicating that `sscanf` couldn't match the format string). If that field extends to the end of `line`, you could then use it directly (`line + nchar`) or copy it into a different string after checking that it is not too long.

If `line`, contrary to its name, contains multiple lines and you want to extract the string up to the newline character, you could use two `%n` formats with a `%*[^\n]` in between (the star suppresses the copy so it avoids overrun problems):

```
char name[NAME_MAX + 1];
int nstart = -1, nend = -1;
int nfield = sscanf(line, "%u - %u - %u, %f , %f , %n%*[^\n]%n", &year, &month,
                    &day, &temp, &uncertainty, &nstart, &nend);
if (nend > 0) {
  if (nend - nstart <= NAME_MAX) {
    memcpy(name, line + nstart, nend - nstart);
    name[nend - nstart] = 0;
  }
  else {
    /* name is too long */
  }
}
else if (nstart > 0) {
  /* Name was 0 bytes long. Sscanf requires that %[ match at least
   * one character; if not, it fails the scan.
   */
  name[0] = 0; /* Perhaps you wanted to signal an error
}
else {
  /* Line didn't match format */
}
```

Obviously, I could have avoid the use of a fixed-length buffer and the need to check for overflow by dynamically allocating the buffer when I know how big it is:

```
char* name = NULL;
// ...
if (nend > 0) 
  name = strndup(line + nstart, nend - nstart);

// or, if you don't like strndup
//   name = malloc(nend - nstart + 1);
//   memcpy(name, line + nstart);
//   name[nend - nstart] = 0;
```

If what you really want is a dynamically allocated string and you have a Posix-compliant `sscanf`, you can avoid that hassle by using an `m` length modifier, which is the all-round simplest solution.

```
char* name = NULL;
int nfield = sscanf(line, "%u - %u - %u, %f , %f , %m[^\n]", &year, &month,
                    &day, &temp, &uncertainty, &name);
```

See your `sscanf` manpage for details. In all cases where `name` is dynamically allocated, don't forget to free() it when you're done with it.

Comment: "if nfield is at least 5 then nchar will contain the offset in line of the name field" is not sufficient .  The return value may be 5, yet `nchar` unchanged due to missing `,`.    Alternative, set `nchar = -1` and see if it changed.

Comment: @chux: good point. I also need to mention that `%[` fails if it matches 0 characters.

Comment: Doesn't `sscanf` return the number of variables read, not the offset?

Comment: @corazza: of course. Please note that `nchar` is **not** the return value of  `sscanf`; it's a value stored by the `%n` conversion, which does provide the offset. The return value of the `sscanf` call is stored in a variable called `nfield`, which was an attempt at documentation.

Comment: @rici ah alright, thanks for the clarification. I wasn't reading carefully:D

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I was reading chapter 2 from the book "Unix System Programming: Communication, Concurrency, Threads " , 2003 edition, and I studied an example that resulted in breaking a string into tokens with an custom delimiter (it could be , or _ or a space or whatever). It used the strtok() C library function. Here is the example tweaked to fill your needs somehow. I will give the 2 files :

makeargv.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* frees all the memory that was allocated by makeargv */
void freemakeargv(char **argv)
{
   if (argv == NULL)
      return;
   if (*argv != NULL)
      free(*argv);
   free(argv);
}
/* Now the function that breaks string s into tokens */ 
int makeargv(const char *s, const char *delimiters, char ***argvp) 
{
   int error;  int i;
   int numtokens;
   const char *snew;
   char *t;
   if ((s == NULL) || (delimiters == NULL) || (argvp == NULL)) 
    { errno = EINVAL; return -1; }
   *argvp = NULL; /* so that a failed call to malloc,will leave it NULL */
      /* now we consume any initial delimiters characters of input s */
   snew = s + strspn(s, delimiters);   /* snew is real start of string */
   if ((t = malloc(strlen(snew) + 1)) == NULL)
      return -1;
   strcpy(t, snew);
   numtokens = 0;
   if (strtok(t, delimiters) != NULL)  /* count number of tokens in s */
      for (numtokens = 1; strtok(NULL, delimiters) != NULL; numtokens++) ;
      /* next,create argument array for ptrs to the tokens */
   if ((*argvp = malloc((numtokens + 1)*sizeof(char *))) == NULL) 
    {
      error = errno;
      free(t);
      errno = error;
      return -1;
    }
      /* now insert pointers-to-tokens into the argument array */
   if (numtokens == 0)  free(t);
    else 
    {
      strcpy(t, snew);
      **argvp = strtok(t, delimiters);
      for (i = 1; i < numtokens; i++)
          *((*argvp) + i) = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }
    *((*argvp) + numtokens) = NULL;      /* append final NULL pointer */
    return numtokens;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int makeargv(const char *s, const char *delimiters, char ***argvp);
void freemakeargv(char **argv);

int main()
{
    char delim[] = ",";
    int i, numtokens;
    char **myargv;  /* memory will be allocated dynamicaly, and has to bee freed before exit */

    char line[] = "1999-08-01,14.547,0.191,United Kingdom-UK";
    if ((numtokens = makeargv(line, delim, &myargv)) == -1) /* nakeargv() allocates memory for myargv, it may fail */
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to construct an argument array for %s\n", line);
      return 1;
    }
   printf(" The argument array contains:\n");
   for (i = 0; i < numtokens; i++)
      printf("%d:%s\n", i, myargv[i]);
   freemakeargv(myargv);    /* do not forget to free the memory! */
   return 0;
}
```

gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o tokenizer main.c makeargv.c

and run it

./tokenizer

Answer (score 0):

Variation on [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50440783/2410359)'s good  approach:

> How to make sscanf read until '\0' character

Use `"%n"` to cope with the "rest of the line".
`"%n"` records the offset of the scan up to that point, if it made it that far.
`%*[^\n]` scans, but does not save all character up to a `'\n'` per OP's "remaining in the line"

Use that to  allocate the ending string.

```
// Some untested code
typedef struct {
  unsigned int year, month, day;
  float temp, uncertainty;
  char *name;
} data_T;

// return 0 on success
int foo(data_T *dest, const char *line) {
  int start = 0;
  int end = 0;
  memset(dest, 0, sizeof *dest); // zero `dest`
  sscanf(line, "%u - %u - %u, %f , %f , %n%*[^\n]%n", 
    &dest->year, &dest->month, &dest->day, &dest->temp, &dest->uncertainty, 
     &start, &end);
  if (start == 0) {
    // line did nor scan properly, return error
    return 1;
  }
  if (end == 0) {
    end = start; // there was no non-white-space text after the `,`
  }
  size_t len = end - start;   
  dest->name = malloc(len + 1u);
  if (dest->name == NULL) {
    // Out of memory
    return 1;
  }
  memcpy(dest->name, line + start, len);
  dest->name[len] = '\0';

  printf("%u-%u-%u,%f,%f, %s\n", 
    dest->year, dest->month, dest->day, dest->temp, dest->uncertainty, dest->name);

  return 0;  // be sure to free dest->name when done with it.
}
```